# Object created with reflection and Html.EditorForModel()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have set of complex objects, which are completely generated using reflection mechanism, all of them implements an empty interface. I want to use `Html.EditorForModel()` to show editors for objects fields, but for right now I can see just an empty page.

If I serialize one of the objects I have such structure in json

```
{
   "ContractingAuthority":
   {
     "FirstName":null,
     "LastName":null
   },
   "ContractInformation":
   {
     "Title":null,
     "Description":null
   }
}
```

So the json serializer can find all fields correctly. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

So far I have such sketch code:

> ```
>         var sequence = GetSequenceMetadata();
> ```

```
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("Particles") { Version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0) };

        var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("ParticlesModule");

        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(string.Format("Particles.ParticlesModule.{0}", type.Name), TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, null);
        typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IParticle));

        foreach (var property in sequence.Items)
        {
            if (property is XmlSchemaElement)
            {
                var element = property as XmlSchemaElement;



                var elementType = GetFieldType(element.ElementSchemaType.TypeCode);

                var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(string.Format("_{0}", element.Name),
                    elementType, FieldAttributes.Private);

                var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(element.Name, PropertyAttributes.None, elementType, null);

                var propertyGetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_value", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, elementType, Type.EmptyTypes);
                var ilGetGenerator = propertyGetter.GetILGenerator();
                ilGetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                ilGetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
                ilGetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                var propertySetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_value", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new[] { elementType });
                var ilSetGenerator = propertySetter.GetILGenerator();
                ilSetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                ilSetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                ilSetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
                ilSetGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(propertyGetter);
                propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(propertySetter);
            }
        }

        var returnType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

        return returnType;
```

After I have the type I simple get ctor and create on instance

> ```
>                     var ctor = entityType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
> ```

```
                    var instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });

                    return instance;
```

In controller class I simple pass model to the view return View(instance).
And in the view itsel i call for Html.EditorForModel().

Comment: when you say "generated using reflection mechanism" - do you mean `TypeBuilder` etc? I just want to be 100% clear...

Comment: Can you show the code you have written so far?